# PHP - Find extra/missing class variables from stdObject

Tags: php, json, api, validation

I am fetching data from an API and it is being normalized to a class object. I am working on writing tests that will fetch data from the API and tell me if the API is sending new data for fields my class doesn't have, or extra fields in the class object that the API is no longer sending.

Lets say I have a User/Address Entity:

```
class User
{
    public $id;
    public $email;
    /**
     * @var Address
     */
    public $address;
    public $name;
}

class Address
{
    public $id;
    public $street;
    public $city;
    public $state;
    public $zip;
}
```

The data I am returned is JSON data when I fetch a user is:

`{"id":1,"address":{"id":44,"street":"123 Main st","street2":null,"city":"Boston","state":"MA","zip":12345},"email":"test@foo.bar","first_name":"bob","last_name":"smith"}`

Formatted:

```
{  
   "id":1,
   "address":{  
      "id":44,
      "street":"123 Main st",
      "street2":null,
      "city":"Boston",
      "state":"MA",
      "zip":12345
   },
   "email":"test@foo.bar",
   "first_name":"bob",
   "last_name":"smith"
}
```

Notice that the API is not sending the `name` field, but is sending `first_name` and `last_name`. The address field is sending `street2` as well.

What is the best way for me to know that my User and Address class are missing fields, and that my User class has a field that is no longer being sent?

Comment: You could write a test case which is run once in a while and then use assert methods. 

But you could also cast them to array and use probably array_walk_recursive to compare elements in both arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the decoded JSON is in `$result` as an array, just check the keys against the class vars.  For the `Address` class:

```
$new = array_diff_key($result['address'], get_class_vars('Address'));
$missing = array_diff_key(get_class_vars('Address'), $result['address']);
```

If you decode to objects then you can cast to an array:

```
$new = array_diff_key((array)$result->address, get_class_vars('Address'));
$missing = array_diff_key(get_class_vars('Address'), (array)$result->address);
```

Or get the object vars:

```
$new = array_diff_key(get_object_vars($result->address), get_class_vars('Address'));
$missing = array_diff_key(get_class_vars('Address'), get_object_vars($result->address));
```

`$new` here means present in the JSON and not in the PHP class and `$missing` means present in the PHP class but not in the JSON.

You should get the idea for the `User` class.  If this is more deeply nested then you can loop, check for an array key or object property named the same as one of your classes and repeat the tests.

Comment: Got me pointed in the right direction with the array_diff_key. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [get_class_vars](https://php.net/get_class_vars) and [property_exists](https://php.net/property_exists) functions should be useful. You can get an array of the public properties belonging to your class and check whether your object has them:

```php
class User
{
    public $id;
    public $email;
    /**
     * @var Address
     */
    public $address;
    public $name;
}

class Address
{
    public $id;
    public $street;
    public $city;
    public $state;
    public $zip;
}


$obj = json_decode("{\"id\":1,\"address\":{\"id\":44,\"street\":\"123 Main st\",\"street2\":null,\"city\":\"Boston\",\"state\":\"MA\",\"zip\":12345},\"email\":\"test@foo.bar\",\"first_name\":\"bob\",\"last_name\":\"smith\"}");

$vars = array_keys(get_class_vars("User"));

$missing_vars = array();
foreach($vars as $v) {
    if (!property_exists($obj, $v)) {
        $missing_vars[] = $v;
    }
}
if (count($missing_vars) > 0) {
    echo "obj is missing these properties: " . implode(", ", $missing_vars) . "\n";
} else {
    echo "all properties present and accounted for!\n";
}
```

Comment: @TimWithers It does, but checking the address of a supplied user is simply a matter of mimicking what I've already done for User. If you need logic to search some arbitrary structure for some list of arbitrary classes, you'll probably need logic specific to the class being checked because PHP is a *weakly typed* language and the properties (and nested objects) of any stdObj will not correspond to any of your user-defined classes.